# Showing all columns in a table except some

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my statement:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN tbl_name WHERE NOT (
FIELD = 'col1' OR FIELD =  'col2'
)
```

I want to reduce it to something like this so that the PHP code is more efficient:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN tbl_name WHERE NOT (
FIELD = 'col1','col2'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  COLUMN_NAME
from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where   TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_name'
        and COLUMN_NAME not in ('col1', 'col2')
```